# SVN checkout from 2 different paths

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

we have an svn repository.

I want to checkout a few folders out of this repository to my local machine.Specifically I want to checkout 7 folders from svn to my workspace which is present at C:/workspace. ( so that after checkout the structure becomes C:/workspace/(all 7 folders)).

The problem is : Out of the 7 folders, 4 are on path1, and the other 3 folders are on path2.

Here's what I have tried,

1. Go to C.
2. Right click workspace,
3. Checkout, then I give path1 and I get the 4 folders. ( now structure becomes       C:/workspace/(4folders from path1)). All ok till here.
   4.Now if I again right click on workspace ( to get the other 3 folders from path2), I do not find the checkout option.
4. I have tried manually creating the folders inside workspace ( using New folder option), and checkout the content from svn, but that makes the folder out of sync with svn ( no greeen tick on workspace).

   I am using the svn tortoise windows shell utility.

   Please suggest what needs to be done to get the structure C:/workspace/( all 7 folders from svn).

Comment: Are these folders all in the same project? I mean, assuming you are using the standard trunk/branches/tags layout, are all these folders somewhere under trunk?

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 is kinda the right way to do it.  But you're right that the `workspace` directory won't be versioned.  That's because you never checked it out - you only checked out directories underneath it.  What you'll get instead is each of the 7 directories having their own `.svn` directory instead of just one at the `workspace` level.  In that case, I don't think you'll be able to commit changes to files in multiple roots.

Another option you might consider is to tag or branch the required folders into another part of your repository and then check that out.

Comment: thanks for the answer, as you have mentioned, I get 7 directories each with its own .svn. How do I tag or branch the required folders ? could you please be a bit detailed ?

Comment: If you want to take that approach, the easiest way is to open TortoiseSVN Repo Browser.  Create the directory in there, and use SVN copy to copy all the required directories into that one.  SVN copy is just like tagging and branching.  You can just drag the directories around in Repo Browser.  Hold Ctrl key down while doing this to copy instead of move.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the other three folders from second repository to a separate folder and move the folders to the first checkout. It works.

1. Go to C.
2. Right click workspace,
3. Checkout path1 and I get the 4 folders.
   (now structure becomes C:/workspace/(4folders
   from path1)).
4. Create a new folder path2 under C
5. Right click and checkolut path 2 (now the structure is path2/(3 folders)
6. Move the three folders to previous checkout folder
   (now the structure is C:/workpace/(7folders)\
7. The second set of 3 folders are versioned (they show green tick). Any checkins in these folders will go to the second SVN path)

Comment: If I move contents of Path2 folder to C:/workspace, then what do I do with the Path2 folder. Should I delete it ? Also, trying your solution makes the entire workspace go out of sync with the repository( no green tick).

Comment: Yes you are right. This was possible in earlier version of SVN. In the new versions (1.7.1+), there is only one top-level .svn folder. In the earlier versions, there used one .svn in each sub-folder, which made this possible. For your use case, you can create two top-level folders path1 (with 4 folders) and path2 (3 folders) and configure the dependencies using this folder structure.

Comment: No I would like to have only this structure C:/workspace/(7 folders). Is there a way ? And, I don't really know what the dependencies are, and how to configure them,hence don't want to try the top level folder option. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Maybe its time to ask why do you want all the 7 sub-folders within a single folder?

Comment: :cause thats the structure my team uses, and it works fine on their workspace.Besides, the application won't run if I change the structure.

Comment: There is one thing you can do. Keep both .svn folders in the location with different names - .svn.path1, .svn.path2. Then rename the to .svn depending the path you are working on. This will of course mean you will not get the "green ticks" for both simultaneously but you can do all SVN operations one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To get get the layout you want, checkout the root of each of the seven folders under `c:/Workspace` - so do 7 distinct checkouts.

In a comment you asked about tagging/branching - don't do this against the folders in `c:/Workspace`. Instead, either;

1. Do it in the repobrowser with the `copy to...` command, or
2. Checkout trunk of each project in a different location and use these for branching/tagging. You may need these anyway for merging (again, don't do that on c:workspace either!).

...then svn switch the folder/s in c:/workspace as necessary.

Since this can of course be error prone, consider scripting the repetitive parts. An ant build.xml would be easy for the checkouts and switches.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a combination of folders which is checkout together frequently, you might consider using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html): On *path1*, set the *svn:externals*-property to get the 4 folders from *path2*.

Alternatively, you can create a completely new folder in either repository and set _svn_externals_ so that all 7 folders are checked out. (Mind that as of Subversion 1.5, you can also use relative definitions for paths inside the same repository.)